# Displaying money in a JTable but preserving the ability to sort as a double

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I have a JTable where one of the columns is an amount in dollars and cents.     I define this TableColumn as a Double and it right justifies and when sorting, it sorts it as a double (not as a string).   This is all well and good.
My problem now is that it truncates trailing zeros.  100.00 is displayed as 100   0.00 is displayed as 0, etc. I tried a TableCellRenderer but although this causes the money column to display with trailing zeros, the amounts are now all left justified and the JTable sees this as a string.
I want the trailing zeros to be retained in displays but also to retain the data type so that sorting and right justifying occur. The datatype does not need to be a double if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Hard to say where you failed, because a custom renderer can render that values in any way that you want, and they don't affect the data type of the model. (Just wanted to say that so that others who are reading this don't think that a custom renderer is the wrong way to go)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the perfect link.    This worked first time.   Just copy the code.

http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/11/table-format-renderers/

Answer (score 3):

If you want to handle money precisely, you should represent it as cents and Integers, or BigInts if you have to handle huge amounts. Floating point numbers can cause problems because they suffer from [precision problems](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems)

This will preserve your ability to sort, remove the problem of trailing zeroes, give you the precision you need, and with a custom renderer, you can get the decimal point where it needs to be.